# Arduino pin erratic behavior?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, switch, breadboard

I've built a switch key matrix (thus the diode, contextually useful schematics below) and me being me, I realised after that I misunderstood a few things about how button really works, to say the least...  So anyway, I want to save it so I plan on a solution which, to my surprise, is half-working: When I remake the entier circuit on a breadboard (mistake & solution), it's working but when I do it with my PCB, it doesn't...

The 5V+ is from a digital pin set to HIGH and I've mesured w/ an oscilloscope the tension between the ground and a digital pin ("Arduino INPUT") on the breadboard and on the PCB, with the input pin connected and not connected:

|  | Connected | Not Connected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BreadBoard | 2.5V+ | 5V+ |
| PCB | 0V+ | 5V+ |

So it's seems like the pin is becoming one with the ground but I can't find anything that could explain this.
I've been testing and trying to understand what the hell was going on for multiple hours now and I runned out of ideas... Does anyone here have an idea of whats might happening ?

[image]

Comment: this may help ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562412/4x4-keyboard-matrix-why-no-pull-down-resistors

Comment: Well, that is helpful ! I still need to really understand it but this link seems to help a lot:
https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=14175

Comment: look at the "initial case" circuit ... change `arduino input` to `arduino output` .... add `arduino input` to switch pin 1

Comment: Yup, I got it but I still would like to understand why it "sinks" the tension...

Answer (score 0):

Are you supplying the breadboard from a 5v power source, other than the one that is supplying the Arduino?

Is there any reason why you are using a diode between the button and the arduino pin?

Arduino can sink and source current and with the 10k resistor that diode is just "dropping" some voltage, i would remove it if you really don't have any other use for it.

If you are supplying the PCB with a different power source than the arduino, you have to "join" the 2 grounds, connect the groud from the power source of the PCB to any ground pin of the arduino. if you could take a photo that could help.

Something like this :

[image]

Comment: There's a diode because it's a part of a key matrix. The 5V+ is from a digital pin set to HIGH so the breadboard is fed with that.
Regarding the 10k resistor, I know it's a mistake and I'm trying to fix it. The thing is, the fix is acting strangely...
What are you using for your schematics btw ?

Comment: But can't you bypass the diode? can you post a picture of how you have the thing connected?

I'm using an old software called Circuit Wizard

Comment: It«s really important that you connect the ground of the pcb power supply (if there is a different one) to the arduino ground

Comment: @O'Schell the info about the diode belongs in the question ... please edit your question and add the info

Comment: Diode info added and the ground on the PCB isn't used in the circuit: I only use the arduino one